# Home network: router + OpenVPN + wireless mesh

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openvpn, mesh-networking

I've recently purchased a Wifi mesh to help improve coverage in my house. So far, it's working fine for everyone in the household for most situations. The only thing I'm having trouble with is trying to access a couple of machines over my OpenVPN connection (that I had no problem with before).

Here is a diagram of my network.

[image: My home network]

I've kept my original router, because it supports OpenVPN/No-IP, and the wifi mesh does not (none of the consumer grade ones do, as far as I can tell).

Every device over wifi and the ones connected via the hub (the hub is necessary because the primary mesh node only has the two ethernet ports on it) works fine. They can get internet, communicate with eachother (I can RDP from My Desktop to Media Server, for instance).

The only problem is that when I'm away from home, and I want to RDP into my media server from my phone. I connect with OpenVPN (which I used *before* I had the mesh, and this all worked fine), but then I can't RDP to the media server.

Here's the OpenVPN config on the router:

[image: OpenVPN config]

I *think* I have to setup Static Routing (the router supports this), but my attempts so far have no worked. Probably because I don't really know what I'm doing.

When I use the Tenda app, it says the IP address from the primary node is 192.168.1.1.

The router IP address is 192.168.0.1. I can connect to it from my desktop and change settings. It says the IP address for the Tenda node is 192.168.0.127.

The IP address for my desktop is 192.168.1.60, and the IP address for my media server is 192.168.1.249.

So, I think that there are two subnets? And from what I've seen from googling, I need to use static routing to forward traffic from one subnet to the other. Here's what I see under "static routing" on the router:

[image: Static routing on tp-link router]

So, any ideas what I should add into Static Routing to make this work? (Or, if not Static Routing, then what?) It's really only the two desktops that I need to access via OpenVPN, so I'm willing to put in settings just to address them specifically, if I have to. But if I could get to every device in my house via OpenVPN, that would be fine too.

Comment: Simplify to one subnet.  You need the equipment docs.  This will be vastly easier than routing for all situations.

Comment: I would love to, but don't know how to. Suppose I have the docs, what should I look for in them?

Comment: In a wired setup, hook up LAN to LAN, Turn DCHP OFF downstream, give devices a Static IP on the main network. If hooking up mesh wirelessly you need to determine how to set up the LAN address on the main mesh device and give it the Static IP.

Comment: As your router works fine with VPN, focus on your range extender.  You don't want the range extender to act as a router - you want it to act as a bridge (which I would have expected to be the default mode).   To convert a router to a bridge, generally you disable DHCP on it and connect to the LAN interface (ie leave the WAN interface disconnected).

Comment: In a Ubiquiti setup I use the controller software to do this

Comment: Not sure if this is your device (or if your device is similar), but the specs for https://www.tendacn.com/product/specification/MW3.html show it as having 2 mode - I posit you have this set up in router mode.  If that's the case, likely all you need to do to fix the problem is change it to Bridge mode.   O

Comment: Does the tenda need to be plugged in to the router? Router should go to switch, tenda should go to switch.  Why is it mediating lan traffic?

Comment: Yes, @davidgo, that's it! I was making it too complicated. Just had to put it into bridge mode. I don't even need the hub (for now); I can just plug everything into the router. Please make that the answer and I'll mark it :)